# jaxb classes generated from the maven-jaxb2-plugin does not go under desired package

Tags: maven, plugins, jaxb2

I am able to generate classes with maven-jaxb2-plugin.
Classes are generated as per below file structure

com.test.vo
      org
          tempuri
                  myobject.java
                myobjectreponse.java

But I wish that classes are generated direct my expected package(com.test.vo).

I have set my plugins like below

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <extension>true</extension>
                        <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/wsdl</schemaDirectory>
                        <packageName>com.test.vo</packageName>
                        <generateDirectory>com.test.vo</generateDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

let me if anyone needs more information

Answer (score 0):

If you replace

```
<packageName>com.test.vo</packageName>
```

with

```
<generatePackage>com.test.vo</generatePackage>
```

your generated classes will be placed under this Java package. Good luck!